# Sorting an object by key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an application where I want to be able to render a stack of content based on an orderId value in the object.

```
{
    "hero": {
        "body": "test body",
        "orderId": 1
    },
    "journey": {
        "body": "test body",
        "orderId": 0
    },
    "banner": {
        "body": "test body",
        "orderId": 2
    }
}
```

- create an array of the keys based on the orderId in the object ["Journey", "Hero", "Banner"]
- be able to order this object by orderId

---

I've tried something like this for the creating the array

```
Object.entries(content).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[1].orderId - b[1].orderId;
});
```

Comment: If you just want the ordered keys, you can use `Object.keys` like: `Object.keys(content).sort((a,b) => content[a].orderId - content[b].orderId)`

Comment: ok - but what about "be able to order this object by orderId" –

Comment: If you want to create a new object, you can pass the sorted entries from your code to: `Object.fromEntries(sortedEntries)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only part that you missing is to get the key and you can get it by using the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the sorted array and retrieve the first element from this array.

```
sortedData.map((a) => a[0])
```

```js
const content = {
  hero: {
    body: "test body",
    orderId: 1,
  },
  journey: {
    body: "test body",
    orderId: 0,
  },
  banner: {
    body: "test body",
    orderId: 2,
  },
};

const result = Object.entries(content)
  .sort((a, b) => a[1].orderId - b[1].orderId)
  .map((a) => a[0]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: ok - but what about "be able to order this object by orderId"

Comment: What should be the expected output for *be able to order this object by orderId*?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68000450/sorting-an-object-by-parameter-value  -- like this

Comment: so you've solved the first part --- making this array stack - create an array of the keys based on the orderId in the object ["Journey", "Hero", "Banner"]

Comment: @TheOldCounty If you're looking to order the object inside the main object then you can't do that. JS stores the object internally. BTW you gonna access the object with keys so it doesn't matter how it stores...

Comment: That was only a part of it - I need to reorder the object itself for a different page

Comment: Since there is a comment from `trincot` that already answers that...

Answer (score 0):

```
let json = {
    "hero": {
      "body": "test body",
      "orderId": 1
    },
    "journey": {
      "body": "test body",
      "orderId": 0
    },
    "banner": {
      "body": "test body",
      "orderId": 2
    }
  }
  let arr = [];
  Object.entries(json).forEach(ele => {
    let keyword = ele[0];
    id = ele[1].orderId;
    arr[id] = keyword;
  })
  console.log(arr)
```

Comment: what if there is one more entry in data `test: {
    body: "test test",
    orderId: 7,
  }` then you will get result as `[ 'journey', 'hero', 'banner', <4 empty items>, 'test' ]`  which OP doesn't want.

Comment: @decpk  Nope it will get  result something like.  [ 'journey', 'hero', 'banner',  'test' ] skips 4 one instead giving no defined by the orderId.. so basically 4 will not exists .... I think you wanted this as  said in the question orderId must define the index !

Comment: Try running this !

Comment: ok - but what about "be able to order this object by orderId"

Comment: @The Old County That's impossible ! and of no use since you always access the object properties with keys (like object.key ) and it doesn't matter which number they get ... Kind of interesting right ! .... Also I really don't understand the meaning of asking this